# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: Unhandled exception type JAXBException Unhandled

Tags: mysql, jaxb

Estoy intentando crear un XML pero me da errar en la primera línea, y no encuentro la solucion, como puedo arreglarlo?

```
public class GenerarXML {

public static void generar(){

        try {
            JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Citas.class);
            Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
            Citas Citas1 = null;
            ArrayList<Owner> ownerr = new ArrayList<>();
            try {
                File fichero = new File("D:\\peval1\\noCatalanes.dat");
                FileInputStream filein = new FileInputStream(fichero);

                ObjectInputStream dataIS = new ObjectInputStream(filein);

                ObjCitas objCitas = (ObjCitas) dataIS.readObject();
                while (true) {
                    objCitas = (ObjCitas) dataIS.readObject();
                    Citas1 = new Citas();

                    Owner owner1 = new Owner();
                    owner1.setCod_Pet(objCitas.getStrCodPet());
                    owner1.setName_Pet(objCitas.getStrNamePet());
                    owner1.setSpecie(objCitas.getStrSpecie());
                    ownerr.add(owner1);

                    ArrayList<Historial> historiales = new ArrayList<>();
                    Historial historial = new Historial();
                    historial.setCod(objCitas.getStrCod());
                    historial.setDate(objCitas.getStrDate());
                    historial.setType(objCitas.getStrType());
                    historial.setCost(objCitas.getStrCost());
                    historiales.add(historial);
                    owner1.setHistorial(historiales);

                }

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                System.out.println("No se ha podido crear el fichero XML, compruebe si esta creado el noCatalanes.dat \n");
            } catch (IOException e) {
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            } 

            try {
                Citas1.setOwner(ownerr);

                marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);             
                marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_ENCODING, "UTF8"); 

                marshaller.marshal(Citas1, new FileWriter("D:\\peval2\\citas.xml"));
                System.out.println("Fichero XML Creado Correctamente. \n");
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }       
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            System.out.println("error");
        }
}

}
```

**Este es el error que me da:**

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation
>   problems: Unhandled exception type JAXBException Unhandled exception
>   type JAXBException
>
> at peval2.GenerarXML.generar(GenerarXML.java:21) at
>   peval2.Principal.main(Principal.java:29)